# Rails 3 Routes issue on form Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

Basically whats happening is I can create a new item that gets saved to my table in my db. but when I go to edit the item, the form opens up, I make the change and then when I go to submit, it takes me to the same url as the edit page and gives me Routing Error No route matches "/support/14/edit" although if you enter that in the address bar it opens the edit form just fine, but doesn't have any of my changes saved. So here is my code.

routes.rb

```
resources :support
```

support_controller.rb

```
def new
  @support_item = Support.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @support_item }
  end
end

# GET /support/1/edit
def edit
  @support_item = Support.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /support
# POST /support.xml
def create
  @support_item = Support.new(params[:support_item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @support_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to("/support", :notice => 'Question was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end

# PUT /support/1
# PUT /support/1.xml
def update
  @support_item = Support.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @support_item.update_attributes(params[:support_item])
      format.html { redirect_to("/", :notice => 'Question was successfully updated.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @support_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

support.rb

```
class Support < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role

  scope :admin_available, order("role_id ASC") do
      Support.all
  end

  def self.available(user)
    questions =   where(:role_id => 1)
    questions +=  where(:role_id => user.roles)
    questions
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
  <% if @support_item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@support_item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @support_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Support item for:" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.find_by_max(5), :id, :name, {:default => 'everyone'} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :question, :class => 'genForm_question'%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :answer %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :answer, :class => 'genForm_textarea' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url, :class => 'genForm_question' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Support Item</h1>

<% form_for @support_item, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
    <%= render 'form', :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Support Item</h1>

<% form_for @support_item, :url => { :action => "edit" }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
        <%= render 'form', :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

I believe thats all the relavent code.

Comment: Why in your edit form are u posting back to edit with a POST verb? Shouldnt you be posting to "update" with PUT verb?

Comment: See @scragz's answer below. Just leave it as form_for @post forboth new and edit, rails works out the mechanics of the endpoint and verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1>Editing Support Item</h1>

<% form_for @support_item do |f| %>
        <%= render 'form', :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

You are overriding the URL. It should be able to be auto-generated like that if you are doing everything with standard rest. If that doesn't work out, just know you don't want to submit to /support_items/1/edit, you want to submit to /support_items/1.

Comment: The problem didn't lay in my code, I did a little digging and found that "support" is reserved by rails. I created the exact same thing with "faq" in place of "support" and it worked seamlessly. Then all I had to do was in the routes.rb file was create resources :faq, :path => 'support'

Comment: That's good. You can still simplify the hell outta those forms though! You'll find Rails is all about letting Rails do what it wants.